# Stuck on Purple splash screen in Ubuntu 18.04 on Third generation (Retina) MacBook Pro

Tags: boot, 18.04, macbook

I had an [old, third generation (Retina) Macbook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro), and I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 (not dual). It was working fine till this morning. After I rebooted, it stuck on the splash screen.

Googled it and removed the graphic drivers and reinstalled AMD graphics again. But still, the issue is the same.

Any possible solutions to fix this issue?

Comment: Anyone help me to restore back to original?

Answer (score 0):

do you get the Grub screen first?

try holding down the 'shift' key while booting.

you could then try 'recovery mode' boot...

to run ' dpkg - repair broken packages'

more alternatives/explanations https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-boot-repair

Last resort: boot from the installer you used (or update the usb drive by d/l'ing latest Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version) back up anything from the current system onto a second USB Drive and reinstall Ubuntu.

hope this helps... cmptrwiz